# Chained Exception versus PrintStackTrace

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Chained Exception is useful in cases in which knowledge of an underlying cause is useful. The Throwable getCause( )method returns the exception that underlies the current exception.

On the other hand, if we call PrintStackTrace() in the catch block, we will have the entire logs printed in the logger file(and in eclipse console). The detailed log will show the exception occurred, and the underlying chain of exceptions as well.

So, what is the primary difference in the usages of both of them.

Comment: I use the stack trace to give me a starting point to find the issues. If I can't find it then I would use a exception to print out specifics. And still won't find whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to provide debug information (PrintStackTrace). The other approach is for actual flow control (Throwable.getCause()).

(Usually) the underlying cause is considered an implementation detail, and therefore should not be used for flow control. Add the information you need to the main exception or create multiple types for exception.